# jQuery for each loop - child element on page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I have an ecommerce 'grouped' product page, with multiple variations of the product displayed. I need to do a live stock check with distributors (XML http post) so am using AJAX to speed up the page.

E.g. - On the grouped product page there are 20 SKUs, each will have a unique stock level looked up via its unique VendorPn code. I need top loop through each part number and fire the AJAX. I have built the script to fire successfully, but cant get it to loop for each child element (it always uses the same value):

```
$('.stockAvailability').each(function(i, el) {
    var $imVPN = $(this)
    var dataString = "VendorPn=" + $(".VendorPn").val();    
    $.ajax({type: "POST",
            url: "ajax/stock-check.php",
            data: dataString,
            dataType:'json',
             success: function(data)
                {
                    if(!data.error)
                    {
                    $(".stockAvailability").prepend(data.stock);

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        alert(data.error);
                    }
                }
            });
         });
```

So the stock level will append to each product variations .stockAvailability. This is all working fine, but i'm having trouble getting it loop for all 'child elements'. The php on the product runs a for loop, so I can grab the .VendorPn for each sku and send it to the AJAX post datastring from there.

Can anyone help as to setting up the jQuery so that for each occurrence of the VendorPn value it finds on the page it runs the above, and updates relevant the .stockAvailability accordingly?

I'm pretty sure its just how I structure the page, and use child elements?

Many Thanks

Comment: It might be because $(".VendorPn").val() is using the same selector each time, you're not referencing it using $(this) context, if you know what I mean.

Comment: Yep! - thanks ... I now have the data coming back OK, but how do i grab the relevant json 'stock' key for the stock in the success function? It just bunches all together ...

Comment: What does your returned json look like?

Comment: Looks good, I have several returns coming back to the page returning the unique values ... e.g: {"stock":"1747","price":"57.49"}. But on the element, it outputs all of the returned 'stock' values, not just the one returned in that iteration

Comment: So the new data is added to all instances of $(".stockAvailability")? If that is the case, you should be able to use $(this).prepend(data.stock)

Comment: In success im trying: $(this).find(".stockAvailability").html(data.stock); not working. I can only get success to append all returned data to the .stockAvailability or just the last returned value using html(data.stock)

Comment: Can you not just add it to the current .stockAvailability loop item?

Comment: Its like the success function ignores the loop, wont update only that child element

Comment: ok,  $(el) should get you the current loop instance of stockAvailability, so try $(el).html(data.stock)

Comment: Thank you, that worked! Would you be able to quickly explain how?

Comment: Where you have function(i,el) in your each function, i is the current index, and el is the current element.  As you've called .each on .stockAvailability, you're effectively saying 'loop over all .stockAvailability elements'. A better explanation: [here](https://api.jquery.com/each/)

Comment: thanks - how can i mark your suggestion as accepted, as is in the comments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posted answer as requested by OP (see comments trail above)

`$(el)` should get you the current loop instance of stockAvailability, so try:

```
     $(el).html(data.stock)
```